# error in elasticserach while importing single line via json

Tags: elasticsearch

ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-121:~$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/movies -d'

{

```
    "mapping": {

            "properties": {

                    "year": {

                            "type": "date"

                    }

            }

    }
```

}'

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"unknown key [mapping] for create index"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"unknown key [mapping] for create index"},"status":400}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

Be careful with typos. "mappings" takes an S

## To solve

```json
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/movies -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "year": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```